# Find the value of $c$ for the joint density function.

Tags: probability

a) Find the value of $c$ for the joint density function.

$f(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             c &   if  & x+y \leq 1, x,y\geq0 \\
             \\ 0 &  \text{other case}
             \end{array}
   \right.$

b) Find $P(X+Y\leq \frac{1}{2})$

**My work**

a) $f$ is a joint density function if $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=1$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0$.

I need determine the area of integration. But i'm stuck here.   because: $0\leq x+y\leq1$. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

This is a picture of the described region, you just have to compute its area.

$$A=\frac12 bh$$

[image]

Edit:

Let $A$ be the area of triangle, $cA = 1$

Comment: Uhmm, then $\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: You don't really need to use integration but if you want, $y$ takes value from $0$ to $1$, once we fix $y$, think of what are the values that $x$ can take in terms of $y$. The previous integration limits that you proposed describes a square of length $1$.

Comment: I think, $c=1$ but, using the definition of density function, i think if $y$ takes the value $0$ to $1$ then $x$ takes the values $0$ to $1-y$ no?

Comment: $c$ is not equal to $1$ as the area of triangle is not $1$. your integration limits are correct now. $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} f(x,y) \,\, dxdy$.

Comment: yeah yeah sorry, is $c=2$ thanks for all (:

Comment: nope, $c$ is not $\frac12$. The area of the triangle is $A=\frac12$, can you solve for $c$? they have to satisfy $Ac=1$.

Comment: is $c=2$ i edit my answer

Comment: congratulations.